# Draw two cylinders and use clipping

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw two cylinders like below, but I would like to use clipping such that the first cylinder covers the second rather then having the second shine through the first, how can I do that:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (db-slice1) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,
    minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm] {};
\node (db-slice2) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,
    minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,
    below=-2.5mm of db-slice1] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Essentially what I want to draw is a database symbol which has three slices each slightly below each other and higher slices clipping lower slices.

I have already looked at [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/disc/), but it has too many gradients and 3D effects.

[image]

**Bonus:** How to draw the hidden line dashed rather then clipping it.

Comment: please condiser to give full snippets like I have modified above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (db-slice1) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,
    minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm, fill=red!30] {A};
\node (db-slice2) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,
    minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,
    above=0pt of db-slice1.before top, anchor=after bottom, fill=blue!30] {B};
\node (db-slice3) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw,
    minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,
    above=0pt of db-slice2.before top, anchor=after bottom, fill=green!30] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that looks good, could you add a short explanation? What did I miss that causes the line to disappear?

Comment: @lanoxx the trick consists in drawing cylinders from bottom to top, while you draw them from top to bottom. This way the second cylinder completely covers the lower one top cover.

Comment: I played around a little with our code and it seems that the key is also to add a filling. If I remove the colors then I can see the back of the cylinder again.

Comment: There are offsets when the text is larger than 1 character. Try instead of 'A' 'hello world'.